# CSS a:links not working as expected

Tags: css

I am trying to create some a links using css

this is my css code:-

```
#footer-links a:link  {
font-size: 12px;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight: normal;
}

#footer-links a:hover  {
font-size: 12px;
color: #73de52;
font-weight: normal;
}
```

here is how i am calling it:-

```
|<span id="filter-links"><a href="www.alink.com">Privacy Policy</a></span>|<span id="filter-links"><a href="www.blink.com">Terms and Conditions</a></span>|
```

the first link works fine. It has white text with a green hover. But the second link reverts to blue text with green hover.

What am I missing?

Comment: Has the second link been visited? `:link` only styles un-visited links: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:link - just remove it if you want to style all links

Comment: isn't it #filter-links instead #foolter-links?

Comment: Check answers below, you make a mistake with footer-links and filter-links.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Class** selector instead of **Id**, as Id is a **unique selector** and always effects over the **first element** having that **Id**.

Thanks

```css
.filter-links a:link {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #262;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.filter-links a:hover {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #73de52;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<span class="filter-links"><a href="www.alink.com">Privacy Policy</a></span>|<span class="filter-links"><a href="www.blink.com">Terms and Conditions</a></span>
```

Comment: so exactly my answer 6 minutes after?

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if you making a mistake here, because your ID definition is filter-links instead of footer-links which you are using in your CSS. Check my snippet below for the correct one.

```css
#filter-links a  {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: normal;
}

#filter-links a:hover  {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #73de52;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<span id="filter-links">
<a href="www.alink.com">Privacy Policy</a>
</span>
|
<span id="filter-links">
<a href="www.blink.com">Terms and Conditions</a>
</span>
```

Hopefully this do the job for you!

Comment: He's not saying that ?